# Apache does not start again after php.ini change

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I just made Change to the `php.ini` of my Localhost `Xampp` Configuration.
After it I wanted to restart the Server but it doesn't start again.
The Log of my `Xampp` Console:

```
15:19:08  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
15:19:09  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
15:19:10  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
15:19:10  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
15:19:10  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
15:19:10  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
15:19:10  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
15:19:10  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
15:19:10  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
15:19:10  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

There are no Entrys in the `apache_error` or `php_error` Logfiles.

I already did a System restart and restored the `php.ini`, but it still doesn't work.

Hope someone has a clue what happened and can help. Thanks in Advance!

**UPDATE:** My second `Xampp` installation still Works. Therefore I think 1st unlikely that there is a Windows Service/Port Problem

Comment: Off-topic. Better suited for SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: Really I thought that Counts to `•software tools commonly used by programmers`

Comment: Yeah I don't think this goes to super user... This is a client side "fakeish" sever for dev. Purposes.

Comment: Why don't you compare your php.ini with the one that is working?

Comment: should I reinstall Apache? I don't really want to do that

Comment: Using your logic, questions about desks should also be allowed, because most programmers use a desk.  No. This question has nothing to do with programming whatsoever. It's asking about configuring Apache.

Comment: There are a barrage of apache config questions on SO. It's borderline related, I'm not sure what my stance is on the "strictly server fault" thing. Whatever. OP, did you check event viewer? `Start Menu -> Run -> eventvwr`

Comment: On SO are a lot of Questions about Apache - it has its on Tag; Yeah ist nothing in the Windows Event Viewer; by the way the ist Win8 Installed, if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

A simple reinstallation solved it